# Finding a maximum value in a dictionary, and dividing all values by this

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary with 100 keys. It looks something like this:

```
{'key1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.95, 0.06, 0.01],'key2': [0.0, 0.1, 0.95,
0.26, 0.11].....'key100': [0.2, 0.0, 0.23, 0.16, 0.21]}
```

I wish to find the the maximum value (in the example above it would be 0.95) and divide all values for all keys by this value. Essentially I would transform the dictionary to a percentage of the maximum. I would be very grateful if someone could advise me on how best to do this in pandas/python.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do this with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'key1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.95, 0.06, 0.01],'key2': [0.0, 0.1, 0.95,
0.26, 0.11], 'key100': [0.2, 0.0, 0.23, 0.16, 0.21]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

max_value = df.max().max()

df /= max_value
```

Comment: Thanks Yuriy - if I were then to covert the new df to a percentage (i.e. all values *100), how best would this be done?

Comment: for key in df:    
    df[key] *=  100

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# First, find the global maximum value
max_val = 0.0
for key, value_list in d.iteritems():
    local_max = max(value_list)
    if local_max > max_val:
        max_val = local_max

# Then divide every item in every value list by the global maximum
new_dict = {}
for key, value_list in d.iteritems():
    new_dict[key] = [x/max_val for x in value_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

the quick-to-write but "dumb" way is to just walk the dict and update a sentinel value if we encounter a higher value:

```
maxval = 0.0
for key in d:
    for val in d[key]:
        if val > maxval:
            maxval = val


for key in d:
    d[key] = [val / maxval for val in d[key]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'key1':......}
from itertools import chain
max_val = max(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
{k:[i/max_val for i in v] for k,v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

try below code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'key1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.95, 0.06, 0.01],'key2': [0.0, 0.1, 0.95,
0.26, 0.11], 'key100': [0.2, 0.0, 0.23, 0.16, 0.21]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
max_value = data.max().unique()
data = data.divide(max_value[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data = {'key1': [0.0, 0.0, 0.95, 0.06, 0.01],
        'key2': [0.0, 0.1, 0.95, 0.26, 0.11],
        'key100': [0.2, 0.0, 0.23, 0.16, 0.21]}
max_in_data = max(max(vals) for vals in data.values())
data = {key: map(lambda x: x/max_in_data, vals) 
        for key, vals in data.items()}
```